# Is there a linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^2$ such that $T(1,0,2) = (1,1)$ and $T(1,-1,4)=(2,2)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Just as title says, I have no idea how to solve this one...
I checked the similar question at the site but the other one has the resulting vectors linearly independent, while in this example I got $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$.
Please give a detailed explanation as I am a bit slow :C

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$\pmatrix{a & b & c \\ d & e & f}$$ be such a transformation. Then we need
\begin{align*}
a+2c &= 1\\
d+ 2f &= 1\\
a-b+4c &= 2\\
d-e+4f &= 2
\end{align*}
Hence we have
$2c = 1+b$ and consequently, $a+b = 0$. Similarly, $d+e = 0$. Thus we can take $a = 1, b = -1, c = 0$, and $d = 1, e = -1, f = 0$. Thus the required transformation is 
$$T = \pmatrix{1 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & -1 & 0}$$

Comment: I got this too, but representing the transformation T with a matrix A(T) is presuming T is a linear transformation, is it alright?

Comment: We need to answer the question "Is there a linear transformation...". Assuming that one exists, we tried to find it. If there were none, we could have got a contradiction and concluded that there is no such transformation.

Comment: I noticed T(a, b, c) = (c/2, c/2) can also generate the desired results, and T seems to be linear. Should I just give one example to show at least one linear transformation giving the result exists?

Comment: Yes. You can give one example to show that such transformation exists.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation :D